# Rename the [majoras-mask-3d] tag to bring it in line with the rest of the [zelda-*] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

*The Legend of Zelda* games typically have long titles, such as *"The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword"* which - other than the first one - we've been abbreviating to [zelda-game-title](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-game-title):

- [legend-of-zelda](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda)
- [zelda-skyward-sword](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-skyward-sword)
- [zelda-link-between-worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-link-between-worlds)
- [zelda-ocarina-of-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-ocarina-of-time)
- [zelda-links-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-links-awakening)
- [zelda-wind-waker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-wind-waker)
- [zelda-twilight-princess](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-twilight-princess)
- [zelda-link-to-the-past](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-link-to-the-past)
- [zelda-majoras-mask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-majoras-mask)
- [zelda-oracle-of-seasons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-oracle-of-seasons)
- [zelda-oracle-of-ages](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-oracle-of-ages)
- [zelda-tri-force-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-tri-force-heroes)
- [zelda-four-swords-ds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-four-swords-ds)
- [zelda-wind-waker-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-wind-waker-hd)
- [zelda-spirit-tracks](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-spirit-tracks)
- [zelda-adventure-of-link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-adventure-of-link)

(Also for completion's sake: [legend-of-zelda-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-of-zelda-series))

However, the new remake of *The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask* is using [majoras-mask-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/majoras-mask-3d), even though [zelda-majoras-mask-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-majoras-mask-3d) would also fit under our 25 character limit.

Should this tag be renamed?

Comment: Also before anyone asks: The game *is* different enough to warrant it's own tag separate to the original, featuring [new controls, changed mechanics, and added content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Majora%27s_Mask_3D#Gameplay)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, seems sensible. Remapped, and synonym added.